# What are the function calls like `BCI2000_INCLUDE( "SOURCEFILTER" )` in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I want to compile the Emotiv EPOC module for BCI2000. In that module CMakeLists file contains following(below the following error log).

The compiler gives the following error,

````
 -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.10586.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (BCI2000_INCLUDE):
Unknown CMake command "BCI2000_INCLUDE".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)```
````

CMakeLists.txt contains this,

```
  ###########################################################################
    ## $Id$
    ## Authors: griffin.milsap@gmail.com
    ## Description: Build information for the Emotiv module

    # Set the executable name
    SET( EXECUTABLE_NAME Emotiv )

    # Set the project specific sources
    SET( SRC_PROJECT
    EmotivADC.cpp 
    lib/edk.imports.cpp
    )
    SET( HDR_PROJECT
    EmotivADC.h
    lib/edk.imports.h
    )

    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/include )

    BCI2000_INCLUDE( "SOURCEFILTER" )

    IF( WIN32 )

    # Create the signal source module
    BCI2000_ADD_SIGNAL_SOURCE_MODULE( 
    "${EXECUTABLE_NAME}" 
    "${SRC_PROJECT}" "${HDR_PROJECT}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dll/edk.dll"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dll/edk_utils.dll"
    )

    ELSE()


    MESSAGE( "--- No Emotiv libraries for this OS. Will not build." )
    ENDIF()
```

How can I fix this?
Looks like they are function calls, but how do I import those function calls from another file if they are declared somewhere?

Comment: `how do I import those function calls from another file if they are declared somewhere?` - [include()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/include.html) a file which declares the function. Actually, absence of  call to `cmake_minimum_required()` (as shown in the warning) suggests, that this file shouldn't be processed by CMake as *standalone*. That is, you should run `cmake` from *other* directory (probably, from the outer directory). Read project's README (or other description).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thats a good point, but there was no readme

Answer (score 0):

The project has to be compiled according to the instructions in this,
https://www.bci2000.org/mediawiki/index.php/Programming_Reference:Build_System
And it says the supported Visual Studio editions are 9(2008) and 10 only or you can compile it with CodeBlocks with MinGW.

And the supportive modules should be included into the source folder of BCI2000 and compile it as a whole project not as seperate modules. Then it recognized the functions defined in the parent project.

There are cMakeList files for submodules. But they cannot be compiled on their own.